# Problem persisting via REST with JoinColumn (Spring Boot/Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm reasonably green with the concept of abstract data modelling, so I'm attempting to make an API using Spring Boot, including String Boot Starter Data JPA, which use Hibernate/Javax persistance.

What I'm trying to do is to be able to post in a request via REST (using Postman to test).  I have this working for normal POJOs, but one I have a JoinColumn it all gets a bit pear-shaped.

For example, I have the following:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "customer_tbl" )
public class Customer
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private long customerId;

@Column( name = "customer_name", nullable = false, unique = true )
private String customerName;
```

...as a parent, of sorts, with the following child...

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "scheme_tbl" )
public class Scheme 
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private long schemeId;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false )
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn( name = "customer_id" )
@OnDelete( action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE )
@JsonProperty( "customer" )
@NotNull
private Customer customer;

@Column( name = "scheme_name", nullable = false, unique = true )
private String schemeName;
```

The idea is that for each `customer`, there may be many `scheme` entries.

I would like to post a `scheme` object via REST, with a reference to the parent `customer` to which the `scheme` will belong, like so

```
{
"customer": { 
    "customer_id" : "1",
    "customerName" :  "TestCustomer"
},
"schemeName": "TestScheme"
}
```

(I've tried many variants of `customer` in this)

I've tried all manner of things, with `customer` being `null` in the `@RequestBody` until I added in `@JsonProperty`.  This is recognised on the `@RequestBody` as a complete `customer` object, but it really doesn't like it and borks with an `unsaved transient entity` exception. The issue is now that it still doesn't do what I am hoping to achieve - by passing in a customer reference that results in having the `customer_id` column appropriately set (or the association made via a fk/lookup).

Is this possible with REST?  I've had similar working in class methods by  simply setting the `${customerId}` in the form using Thymeleaf, which also returns a `scheme` object and happily persists

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out.

The issue was caused by the ambiguity between `customer`, the variable in the `Scheme` object, and (I assume) `Customer` the object.

Despite the fact that the POJO contains an object, rather than a variable, when I refactored the object's variable in the Scheme POJO to `customerId`, it all started working.  Feels unnatural to call the object an ID at this stage, but it works.

`Scheme` POJO now has the following variable:

```
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false )
@JoinColumn( name = "customer_id", nullable = false )
@OnDelete( action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE )
private Customer customerId;
```

and the insert was done by posting...

```
{
"customerId": { "customerId": "1"},
"schemeName": "TestScheme"
}
```

I was able to set the customer within the API by looking up the `Customer` via the `customerId` and setting it back to the `Scheme` object prior to persistence.